# Exported and Unexported fields in Go Language

Tags: go

I have a function in Go, the return value of which I hope to encode using gob. The return value is a struct pointer. However even though I do understand what exported variables are, I am not quite sure how to get it working.

Here is what my function is like

```
fun loadXYZ(root *structABC) *structABC{
    const once = "stateData.bin"
    rd, errr := ioutil.ReadFile(once)
    if errr!=nil{

        //Do some computation and store in "root"

        buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
        errr = gob.NewEncoder(buf).Encode(root)
        if errr != nil {
            panic(errr)
        }
        errr = ioutil.WriteFile(once, buf.Bytes(), 0666)
        if errr != nil {
            panic(errr)
        }
        return root
    }
    var d *structABC
    errr = gob.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(rd)).Decode(&d)
    if errr != nil {
         panic(errr)
    }
    return d
}
```

This is the error I get

```
panic: gob: type main.stateNode has no exported fields
```

I know why the error is occurring. But can someone help me solve it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In go, fields and variables that start with an Uppercase letter are "Exported", and are visible to other packages. Fields that start with a lowercase letter are "unexported", and are only visible inside their own package.

The encoding/gob package depends on reflection to encode values, and can only see *exported* struct fields.

In order to make things encodable, capitalize the first letter of each field name in your `stateNode` struct that you want to be saved.

Comment: The clarity of your statement helped me track the issue. Many thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Exported field it's a filed which name started with capitalized char like:

```
type stateNode struct {
    ImExported string // Exported
    butImNot string // unexported
}
```